# Правомерно ли изменять неблагозвучные имена в переводах?

Tags: переводы

Несколько раз я сталкивалась с тем, что в переводах художественных произведений неблагозвучные для нашего слуха имена слегка изменяли. В частности, приходит на ум герой книг Р. Сальваторе Дзирт до'Урден, которого в оригинале зовут Drizzt Do’Urden.
Так вот, интересно, допускаются ли такие изменения имен при переводе?

Comment: Толкин, насколько знаю, сам просил в его романах переводить и фамилии.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вполне допустимо. Я с трудом смог бы всерьёз воспринимать историю про ДриззтА.

Более того изменять имена стоит, даже в том случае, если они благозвучные, но в русском языке имеют другие, нежели у автора, посылы. Например, если в книге обыгрывается библейский сюжет, зачастую лучше перевести имя героя как в библии, а не как в произведении. Скажем Дэвида, в таком случае лучше сделать Давидом. Подобное нужно сделать, и если у персонажа "говорящая фамилия".

Answer (score 4):

Не могу добавлять комментарии, но хочется дополнить ответ [[@behemothus](/users/445/behemothus)](/users/445/behemothus) относительно неудачных переводов имён -- точнее, непереводов. Перенесите куда следует, пожалуйста.
Попался мне однажды изданный в 90-е детектив Стаута, где героиня говорит Арчи Гудвину что-то вроде "Вы невозмутимы, как Ситтин Булл". И сноска: "Ситтин Булл -- известный индейский вождь...". Индейские прозвища, на мой взгляд, надо переводить в книгах любого жанра.

Comment: Я могу сделать комментарикм, но не вижу в том смысла. Ваша реплика достойна быть ответом.  
По сути.  
Ситтинг Булл ("Татанка Ийотаке") - достаточно известный персонаж чтобы его переводить. А если переводить, то как? Сидящий бык - не совсем точно. Вы когла-нибудь видели ***сидящего*** быка? По-русски надо бы сказать "лежащий". И не бык, а бизон. 
Но с другой стороны, англичане начав переводить индейские имена уже и так всех запутали.  
Короче, я не знаток творчества Стаута, но по мне стоило бы либо не переводить, либо дополнять перевод "званием": ***как индейский вождь Сидящий Бык".

Comment: Я рассуждаю так: во-первых, индейские имена "говорящие" (хотя в данном случае, пожалуй, смысл к делу не относится), во-вторых, в оригинале оно уже переведено, значит, надо и дальше быть последовательными. Об анатомии быков, если честно, не задумывалась... Ну, в конце концов, он же не настоящий, ему можно) Лучшее, на что хватило моей фантазии, -- перевести имя и оставить сноску, но ваш второй вариант, думаю, идеален.

Answer (score 3):

Сложный вопрос...
В целом я против "перевода" имен собственных во "взрослых" неавторизированных  произведениях. Детская литература - особая статья, тут действительно перевод граничит с пересказом, при необходимости "перевод" фамилий вполне уместен. 
Но в обычной литературе для взрослых лучшще десять раз подумать.
Ну какой смысл, простите, делать Эркюля Пуаро Геркулесом или, скажем, Коробочку и Собакевича Боксом и Доггером?
По поводу говорящих фамилий - тоже не все так просто. 
Мы вот тут какое-то время назад крепко поспорили насчет фамилий героев "Обломова". По мне так они совсем не "говорящие". Но я вроде как оказался в меньшинстве. Так что опять это только авторское чутье может сказать есть тут ирония - и насколько глубокая. Но эта же интуиция может крепко подвести переводчика. 
Классически пример безусловно правильного перевода - майор Майор Майор ("Уловка-22"). "Майор Майджер Мэйджер" было бы просто непонятно. 
А вот примеров неудачных переводов я что-то и не подберу... Может потому, что в целом такой перевод редко становится чем-то значимым в литературе.

Comment: У меня, кажется, есть такой знаменательный пример: из популярного мультфильма - Губка Боб Квадратные Штаны!!:-) (от англ. SpongeBob SquarePants). Вообще говоря, русским переводчикам (и дублерам) игрового кино и мультипликации надо бы руки и головы поотрывать. Но это уже другая тема..:-)

Comment: А к чему этот пример?! Т.е. сам по себе он, наверное, смешон, но акие выводы из него модно сделать?

Comment: По поводу Вашего замечания о недостатке неудачных переводов имен собственных. Хотя, может, мой не совсем уместен, поскольку разговор шел о литературе, а не о кино. Я в принципе против перевода имен собственных, но признаю, что и это правило допускает исключения (но не в примере, приведенном в вопросе). Вот, может покажется любопытным ) http://inabove.ru/oshibki-perevoda/

Comment: Просто лыко в строку? Ну нехай будет. 
Я было думал, что есть о чем поспорить или что-то ипереосмыслить...

Comment: И ещё один удачный пример перевода: Смок и Малыш (Джек Лондон). Слово smoke многогранное, и идёт игра слов, которую нельзя передать. Поэтому в моём издании все значения описаны в сноске, но имя не переведено. Зато Шорти было бы достаточно неказисто, и к тому же совсем непонятно.
А названия Белое Безмолвие и Зов Предков звучат даже лучше, чем оригинал (Белая тишина и Зов дикости/природы).

Answer (score 1):

Есть разные виды переводов. Например, в книгах Толкиена одного из главных героев могут называть как Беггинс (от Baggins), так и Сумкинсом. В первом случае, человеку, не знающему английский, смысловая нагрузка фамилии будет неясна. Во втором же она понятна, но могут быть потеряны нюансы, как при переводах бывает, может пропасть игра слов автора, да и разные переводы будут выглядеть немного по-разному. Я бы имена собственные вообще оставлял без перевода по возможности или указывал бы оригинальное написание хотя бы в примечаниях. Но тут уж кто во что горазд.

Comment: А можно и Федором Сумкиным (с) Гоблин ))))))

Answer (score 1):

***("Уловка-28").***

У этой "Уловки" другой номер :)

Comment: Да, конечно. Спасибо. Поправил.